# Why does a margin appear on the right side of my site?

Tags: css, html, web, margin

HI hope someone can help answer my question its really starting to bug me!

The site is here http://www.calypsopretattoo.com/

When you click on the about tab the information comes up but a margin on the right hand side of the page appears and creates a massive white space?

I've tried editing the css a number of times but nothing. any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#aboutp
{
width:100%;
}
```

causes the issue..remove it...:)

Comment: Thank you!! I dont know why I didnt see this :/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:100%;` form `#aboutp` ID this will work

Answer (score 0):

the parent div miss a position relative.

**you use position absolute without using position relative to parent div**

```
div {
    height: 900px;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative; /*add to inline style or make a class for this parent div*/
}
```